# videojs is not working in IE 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, fancybox, video.js

I am using videojs and fancybox to display video dynamically on an overlay. But the flash fallback is not working in IE 8. Can't find out what is wrong with the code.

```
var c = "filename";
var content = '<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls autoplay  preload="auto" width="640" height="480" >'+
                            '<source src="video/'+c+'.mp4" type="video/mp4">'+
                            '<source src="video/'+c+'.webm" type="video/webm">'+
                            '<source src="video/'+c+'.ogv" type="video/ogg">'+
                            '</video>';
            $.fancybox({
                'padding': 0,
                'autoScale': false,
                'transitionIn': 'none',
                'transitionOut': 'none',
                'width': 640,
                'height': 479,
                'content': content
            });
```

I have also specified the path to the swf player file as i am using a hosted version of videojs

```
<script src="js/video-js/video.min.js"></script>
<script>
  _V_.options.flash.swf = "js/video-js/video-js.swf"
</script>
```

somebody please tell me what is wrong with my code. In IE 8, only the close button of fancybox is showing up in the overlay. It works perfectly in all other browsers

Answer (score 0):

IE 8 blocks local `.swf` files.

Try to upload your project to server and test from there.
Make sure that your path to the `.swf` file is correct.